# Need way to send specific application audio as mic output

Tags: gratis, audio, windows-10, microphone, steam

I would like a way to send the sound from a program running on my pc to the microphone output as well as capturing the audio from my microphone as well. Ex. play music on steam in-game browser so only those in game other than me can hear it, and i can speak into my mic at the same time. Details and fancy construction not required. Windows 10 and free.

Comment: What is your operating system and budget? Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information thanks! :-)

Comment: Please edit your question to add this information. Comments get deleted.